# "User not signed in" error when I try to send an embedded chart via email

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Spreadsheet with an embedded chart. I'm using this code to send the chart via email:

```
var charts = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getCharts();
MailApp.sendEmail(      
    "recipient@example.com",
    "Income Charts",      
    "Here's the latest income charts",      
    {attachments: charts });
```

But I only get an image with "User not signed in" error. If I make the spreadsheet public it works, but I don't want to do that. I need the spreadsheet private.

[image]

Comment: [Issue 1571](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1571) was raised for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to see this as well. In fact, I even tried to save it to Drive first and then it was still happening. Diving into it some more, this has to do with the Security and Permissions.

If you make your sheet readable without signing in this works like a charm. So go to "Share" on the top right of the spreadsheet and set the settings to - 'Anyone with the link' (you'll have to click through "Change" against the "Private" row in the dialog prior).

[image: Sharing settings]

This makes sense as Apps Script is in essence a "user" trying to access the spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I can't have my spreadsheet public just for the script to work, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Couple of other options -  (1) build a chart web app include link to that in the email and keep the spreadsheet private - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard and (2) use Charts image API https://developers.google.com/chart/image/ by sending up your data from spreadsheet to get an image you can attach to an email. You can also log an item in the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) for this request.

Comment: "This makes sense as Apps Script is in essence a 'user' trying to access the spreadsheet." - BUT that user is ME! And I'm logged in, otherwise the script wouldn't run as me. Is there any update on this, Arun, because the same happens when trying to import a chart into a doc as an inline image. Why is there such a restriction on the image, but not the sheet itself? (My script can access that!)